# Emberjs + Rails: /api or respond_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, ember-rails

I'm going to use Emberjs to an existing Rails app and itt have already some scaffold resources.

In [this](http://www.devmynd.com/blog/2013-3-rails-ember-js) guide I've read that is better to create a path like: "/api/posts" to handle request for emberjs. 
But I know that Rails responds to JSON if I pass ".json" to my url: e.g.; /posts.json

So, should I create a /api or I could use my default controller to handle JSON? which is the better choise?
If I use default controller i'll use something like

```
 def index
    @posts = Post.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @posts.to_json }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution might be to hook into the `buildURL` function of your `RESTAdapter` and adding the `.json` suffix yourself. This could look something like this:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
    var url = this._super(record, suffix);
    return url + ".json";
  }
})
```

Hope it helps.